# Question about poisson and probability/exponential distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution

I'm a little confused about this question I was given:

"Calls arrive at a tech support center with a mean of 4 per hour. Assuming the number of calls received in 1hr is described by a Poisson distribution, find the probability that there is more than 20 min between the arrivals of randomly selected successive calls.

λ = 4, but since it is exponential, it is 1/4. The formula I think I need is \int_0^w \lambda e^{-\lambda t} dt

◂∫▸
    
      
        
          ∫
          0
          w
        
        
          λ
          ⁢
          
            ◂◽˙▸
            
              e
              
                −
                
                  λ
                  ⁢
                  t
                
              
            
          
        
        
          d
          ⁣
          t

but I cant figure out what my w should be.

Comment: Sorry, I can't figure out how to edit the formula, but its the one in the only answer to this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235154/probability-question-poisson-and-pmf

Answer (score 0):

Call $X=\text{number of calls per twenty minutes}$. That $X$ is Poisson-distributed with $\lambda=4/3$. Compute $P(X=0)$.

Comment: when I plug that into the formula -e^-λx, I dont get the right answer